# Is Windows task manager showing memory usage inaccurately?

Tags: windows, memory, profiler, taskmanager

I am writing a huffman coding and decoding in python and when I run it, windows task manager goes to 100% and jumps up to 5GB of RAM usage under my python project. I installed Memory_profiler for python, to see what is going on and there was not much going on. Windows jumps to those high values in places where profiler showed me 7MB or 180MB increments. What should I trust? My laptop does get laggy a lot when I get to those values.
[image: memory_profiler]